# How to convert 'Results Per Page' drop down over to links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a drop down that has multiple values in it (i.e. 50, 100, 200, etc..) which when selected and a button clicked reloads the page and filters a data table to shows however many results were selected.

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="form-inline" name="normal" id="SearchResultsForm">
    <select name="limitNumberOfResults" id="limitNumberOfResultsPerPage" 
     class="single">  
        <option value="10">10</option>  
        <option value="20" selected="selected">20</option>  
        <option value="30">30</option>  
        <option value="40">40</option>  
        <option value="50">50</option>  
        <option value="100">100</option>  
        <option value="200">200</option>  
    </select>
   <input type="submit" class="button" value="Show" name="submitbutton"/>          
</form>
```

I'd like to convert this from a drop down over to a list of links. How would I go about doing this?

I was trying to use something like the following.

```
<a href="#" onclick="SearchResultsForm.submit();return false;">
                                10
                            </a>
<a href="#" onclick="SearchResultsForm.submit();return false;">
                                20
                            </a>
```

However, I'm not sure how to get the results per page value to be recognized.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm not sure how to get the results per page value to be recognized." ? Questions should include a thorough definition of what went wrong. Show the exact code you are using to try access the `limitNumberOfResults` on the server. Also, do you want a fixed number of items per page?

Comment: When using a link to filter the results per page I'm not clear how to get the value I've clicked to be recognized when the page reloads. If I click '50' results per page I'd like to get only 50 results. Using the href link I posted the page just refreshes. I can't post all the code as there's a whole lot. I tried to post just the sections of code I'm looking at.

Comment: Did you delete the `select` from the page?

Comment: Yes, I removed the select from the page. Now I'm trying to figure out how to use links to produce the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you click 10 go to same page with `?limitNumberOfResults=10` then get that value write your code to get result.

```
<a href="?limitNumberOfResults=10">10</a>

$per_page = $_REQUEST['limitNumberOfResults'];
```

Comment: The name of the field is `limitNumberOfResults`

Comment: <a href="?limitNumberOfResults=10">10</a>

Comment: This won't work if the form has other fields that have to be submitted, it will also lose any existing parameters. It's still fixable, the OP can make sure the links is constructed maintaining existing parameters

Answer (score 1):

[Jakir Hossain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34884244/227299) works (and doesn't require JavaScript) but may require reworking the links to include current state.

Another possibility is for you to use a hidden field and update it when the links are clicked; it does require JavaScript, but you don't have to know about any other parameters that are passed to the server.

```
<input type="hidden" name="limitNumberOfResults" value="20" />

<a href="#" data-result-count="10" class="set-result-count">10</a>
<a href="#" data-result-count="20" class="set-result-count">20</a>

var form = document.getElementById('SearchResultsForm');

// Using event delegation to register clicks on the links
form.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A' && e.target.classList.contains('set-result-count') ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    form.elements.limitNumberOfResults.value = e.target.getAttribute('data-result-count');   
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<select onchange='this.form.submit();'></select>` in select tag so that when options are changed form gets submitted and you get the results per page value

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I'd like to completely get rid of the <select> drop down and go with just links. I just need to have the links work the same as the drop down so when a link is clicked it filters the results per page.